# Prevent user from changing data in websql via debugger

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, firefox

How do you make sure that user cannot change websql database data via debugger of firefox or chrome? Currently I can run queries to insert, update and delete data.

How does this impact the security of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generate checksum for each row. wanna more security? generate checksum on the server, and validate on the server too. but it will be slow to do this. or you could generate checksum on the clientside, save it on the server, and validate later.

Comment: If the checksum is generated via Javascript, how do i make sure that user cannot tamper with it? If the data is supposed to be generated/modified on browser, then how do i keep server in synch with the browser?

Comment: it's tough... i think the all on server generation/validation is more secure. but in fact if the posted data is altered, the server has no idea. maybe we should cover the source of these data, not data itself.

Comment: Validation must always at least be done on the server, you can never trust the client. You can of course also have validation on the client side, just to avoid sending incorrect data to the server and waiting for the server's response.